# Can't get OnCollisionEnter to work with Mesh Collider when using Leap Motion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I am trying to use leap motion to interact with a couple of other game objects. At a very simple level, I have a cube which I need to interact with. For this, I wrote a script -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoorDetector : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
}
```

This should ideally display a Hello in the console on Collision, but it doesn't. I have a mesh collider applied to the body and for the hands, I'm using the RigidRoundHand prefabs. I tried applying a rigidbody (in case the prefabs don't do it already), but that did not work as well.

Comment: Try Box Collider instead of Mesh Collider  and let me know if it works.

Comment: Have you set collision detection to continuous in the rigidbody? This takes more CPU but detects fast moving collisions better

Comment: @Programmer I did exactly that after I posted the question and it worked. Any idea why mesh collider messes up?

Comment: @Zeokav Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using *Mesh Collider* so you must enable *Convex* on the *Mesh Collider*.

[image]

If this does not solve your problem, simply use the *Box Collider* like I mentioned in the comment section.

Comment: I just chose to use a box collider. Thanks!

Comment: @Zeokav Yeah, I would do that too since it is more efficient to use Box Collider. Just wanted to show those with *Mesh Collider* how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you put RigidBody on that cube where is this script. At least one of colliding object needs to have RigidBody. Also disable IsTrigger in Colliders of Cube and every interactible object.